# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[-0.8783137 0.05478287 -0.08827557 0.69203985 0.06209986]'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, floating-point, series, valueerror

I am trying to make this string '[-0.8783137 0.05478287 -0.08827557 0.69203985 0.06209986]' to float, but it is giving me an error. Actually, in my dataframe, this column is of object type, column has 768 values in each row, and I want to make it float type for these embedded values.

I have tried these codes to convert to float but could not solve them. It is giving this error.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'encoded_values': ['[-0.8783137, 0.05478287, -0.08827557, 0.69203985, 0.06209986]', 
                            '[0.31444644, -0.6546649, 0.7211526, 0.9819127, 0.74042267]']})
```

```
df['encoded_values']=df['encoded_values'].astype(float)
df['encoded_values'] = df['encoded_values'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)
df['encoded_values'] = pd.to_numeric(df['encoded_values'], downcast='float')
```

Comment: What happens if you use `apply` and `eval`, i.e., `df['encoded_values']=df['encoded_values'].apply(eval)`?

Comment: It is giving error

Comment: It works for me: online solution: https://onecompiler.com/python/3z5yngx3h

Comment: my values are too large 768 values.. it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

String accessors are the perfect solution for such problems.

```py
df.encoded_values.str.strip("[]").str.split(", ", expand=True, regex=False).astype(float)
```

Output:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -0.878314 | 0.054783 | -0.088276 | 0.692040 | 0.062100 |
| 1 | 0.314446 | -0.654665 | 0.721153 | 0.981913 | 0.740423 |

Comment: but it is showing this error--- Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @BadrunNessaAntu It depends on the pandas version as the type of the column is `object`. In this case try to add `.astype("string")` before the first string accessor. So `df.encoded_values.astype("string").str.strip("[]").str.split(", ", expand=True, regex=False).astype(float)`.